# Why is my texture streching even on using GL_REPEAT?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, textures, texture-mapping

[image]This is my output :![enter image description here][2]

The image is stretched when my walls are long and squeezed when they are small.

My code for loading texture, loadTGATexture method is from the superBible.

```
glGenTextures(1,&texture);  
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);   
LoadTGATexture(textureFile, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT);
```

The code snippet where I am giving the texture coordinates are :
(j is index of a wall of the building)

```
    buildingArray[j][0] = n2.x;
    buildingArray[j][3] = 0;
    buildingArray[j][4] = n2.y;

    texBlgArray[j][0] = repeat_after_length;
    texBlgArray[j][5] = 0;

    normals[j][0] = normal.x;
    normals[j][6] = normal.y;
    normals[j][7] = normal.z;

    j++;
```

I set repeat after length to 1.

I think that as texture GL_REPEAT happens if length is > 1, I should set that to some value greater than one, but if I do so, the windows in texture become very small and large no. of windows are visible. I want to tile the texture, I dont want any change in dimensions of my orignal texture image :[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: When you say "from the superBible", do you mean you implemented it yourself or literally linked to it and are calling it?

Comment: @Hydronium copy pasted their method in my code... it workes fine on ground and other objects, pasted the code after edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your texture coordinates are probably normalized even on long walls (i.e. they have [0,0] at the left corner and [1,1] at the bottom right). If you want texture to repeat you need coordinates *exceeding* 1.0. So, if the length of a triangle side is x, the texture should range over x * some k.

Comment: 2I followed your suggestion, but doing so makes the windows tiny and a huge number of them, shown in EDIT.

Comment: @Anubha from what I see, you have just multiplied each and every of them by a constant factor. You were to multiply only the ones on affected walls instead. IOW create *appropriate* texture coordinates for each wall.

Comment: float wallLength = sqrt((n1.x - n2.x) * (n1.x - 2.x) + (n1.y - n2.y) * (n1.y - n2.y)); // distance formula for wall length

  // the length after which the texture will repeat //
  int repeat_after_length = wallLength * 0.2;  // I took this wall length * 0.2 for maximum texture coordinate.

Comment: are you seriously calculating "wall length" by using normal vectors? That's a terrible misunderstanding

Comment: no, n1 and n2 are nodes having x and y coordinates of the wall endings, they are not normals, I am just trying things randomly, going to think now, thanks, I think you pointed me in right direction.

Comment: thanks bartek, that indeed was the problem, I was replacing the length side 1 unit with the wall length, but the height side I kept 1 only, so after replacing it with height, the textures are now perfect.